# Definite integral of [{Cos^-1(x)}]/√(1-x^2) from 0 to 1

Tags: definite-integrals

If we substitute $cos^{-1}(x)$ with $z$ then,corresponding values of $x=1$ are $z=0,2\pi,4\pi...$
And correspond values of $x=0$ are $z=\pi/2,3\pi/2,5\pi/2...$

Now if for $x$ belongs to $[0,1]$ corresponding value is taken $z$ belongs to $[\pi/2,0]$ then the value of integral comes out to be $(\pi^2)/8$ but for $z$ belongs to $[5\pi/2,2\pi]$ the value of integral comes out to be $9(\pi^2)/8$

Which interval should be taken?

I apologise for stating anything wrong if I have done any.

Edit: previously the question was written about {cos^-1(x)}^2 by mistake

Comment: Is $\cos^{-1}$ the inverse function of $\cos$ or $\frac{1}{\cos}$?

Comment: $\arccos$ is by definition the inverse of the function $\left.\cos\right\rvert_{[0,\pi]}:[0,\pi]\to[-1,1]$ and usually the preferred section of $\cos$ in the real variable is that one.

Comment: I think, if we consider $y=\frac{cos^{-1}(x)^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$, then $y$ takes only non-negative values and thus, we will consider the first quadrant. Thus the former interval must be considered.

Comment: Do we have to consider principle values only?@Gae.S

Answer (score 1):

As @Gae.S. notes, you should take $\arccos0=\pi/2,\,\arccos1=0$ so$$\int_0^1\frac{\arccos^2xdx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\left[-\frac13\arccos^3x\right]_0^1=\frac{\pi^3}{24}.$$

Comment: So basically we have to consider the principle value,right?

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{(\cos^{-1}x)^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx$$
Let $\cos^{-1} x=t \implies -\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} =dt$
So $$=\int_{0}^{\pi/2} t^2 dt= \frac{t^3}{3}|_{0}^{\pi/2}=\frac{\pi^3}{24}.$$